# Eclipse Juno - turn off package-info.java generation?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-juno

When you add a new package in Eclipse Juno it auto-creates a package-info.java file. This is just clutter for me. Is there any way to turn this auto-create off? I've looked in the window -> preferences but can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, on my computer it doesn't automatically create this package-info.java file. Actually, when you create a new package, you are presented with the following wizard:

[image]

I have put a red box around the checkbox that control the file creation. If you unselect that box, it will not create the file, and it will stay unchecked next time you create a package.

Comment: Damn it, I totally missed that in the dialog. Thanks!